# How can I make a Divi theme dropdown in WordPress stay open until I click?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming, dropdown, divi

I have a WordPress site using the Divi theme. I have a dropdown in the navbar that I want to stay open until I click somewhere with the mouse. My trouble is, I don't understand the CSS of the dropdown. I don't know which CSS class to use for opening/closing the dropdown programatically.

The dropdown is the lime green one in the top right of the page with label "Våra erbjudanden", see the screenshot:
[image]

So in short, which Divi classes are used to toggle dropdowns? How would you go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make the dropdown stay open after hover, you can use the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    spriderMain.run();
});

var spriderMain = {

    run() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.onAnyClick, true); 
        this.fixDropdown();
    },

    fixDropdown() {
        var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li")[1];
        dropdown.addEventListener("mouseover", this.onDropdownMouseOver);
    },

    onAnyClick() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li > ul")[0];
            dropdown.style.visibility = "hidden";
            dropdown.style.opacity = "0";
            var dropdownBox = document.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li")[1];
            dropdownBox.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
            dropdown.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        }, 100);
    },

    onDropdownMouseOver() {
        var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li > ul")[0];
        dropdown.style.visibility = "visible";
        dropdown.style.opacity = "1";
    }
};
```

However, a problem might cause the dropdown to reopen on hover, although it already has been opened. This issue is discussed here:
[How can I prevent the dropdown from animating/reopening again when already open in WordPress Divi theme site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881099/how-can-i-prevent-the-dropdown-from-animating-reopening-again-when-already-open?noredirect=1#comment114711393_64881099)